# PSTricks for Mac

Tags: pstricks

I got MacTex installed and am using Texworks. I wanted to recreate an old PDF from my `.tex` files and I'm having some problems.

I got 1 file which tells tex to include all the others and within some `.tex` files I'm using `PSTricks`.

In that master file i got the

```
\include{pstricks}
```

statement and the `pstrick.sty` is within the same folder as the `.tex` files. Still Texworks struggles to compile my files to pdf. What could be the problem? I think it's most likely just because I've got my files within the wrong directory but I'm not quite sure.

thanks in advance!

Comment: `\include` is a command for including external text files and not packages. Cretae a small test document and run it with `xelatex`

Comment: If you want to use pdfLaTeX, you should write `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` instead, and launch pdflatex with the `--shell-escape` switch.